# How to find duration of a webm (opus) audio file in seconds (in a js program)?

Tags: javascript, audio, duration, webm, mediadevices

On a javascript web page I generate an audio message, using HTML5 Media API, and I send it through socketio to a nodejs server that save the file on disk. It all works.

Javascript chunk, client side:

```
navigator.mediaDevices
  .getUserMedia({ audio: true })
    .then(stream => {

      const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream)
      ...
      }
```

Server side I succesfully save the webm/opus file:

```
$ ll audiofiles/audiofile.webm
-rw-rw-r-- 1 username 180K May 29 21:04 audiofiles/audiofile.webm
```

Using vlc player, I see that the duration in seconds is almost 28 seconds.

let's check with mediainfo / ffmpeg:

Using `mediainfo`:

```
$ mediainfo audiofiles/audiofile.webm
General
Complete name                            : audiofiles/audiofile.webm
Format                                   : WebM
Format version                           : Version 4 / Version 2
File size                                : 180 KiB
Writing application                      : Chrome
Writing library                          : Chrome
IsTruncated                              : Yes

Audio
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : Opus
Codec ID                                 : A_OPUS
Channel(s)                               : 1 channel
Channel positions                        : Front: C
Sampling rate                            : 48.0 kHz
Bit depth                                : 32 bits
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Language                                 : English
Default                                  : Yes
Forced                                   : No
```

Using `ffmpeg`:

```
$ ffmpeg -hide_banner -i audiofiles/audiofile.webm
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'audiofiles/audiofile.webm':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Chrome
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0(eng): Audio: opus, 48000 Hz, mono, fltp (default)
At least one output file must be specified
```

My question is:

**How can I trace, server side, on the node server log file, the length in seconds of the webm audio file?**

I need to have the approssimative time duration (in seconds) of the file. Possibly using a nodejs function.

A bad/rough solution in runtime could be to empirically map the length in bytes of the file with the length in seconds...By example for the specific encoding/format: 1000 bytes ~= 1 sec.

Any better idea to measure the duration of the audio file, possibly in the nodejs code?

Answer (score 0):

*Node.js* isn't famous for its audio possibilities.

I like your empirical approach of mapping the length of file to determine the duration, and I'm sure you could get some results if you can extract the sample rate or infos like that to make your calculation, but if you have access to *ffmpeg* in your environment, I would personally use a subprocess to obtain that information:

```
const { exec } = require('child_process');

let your_webm_file = 'audiofiles/audiofile.webm';

// https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/FFprobeTips#Duration
let cmd_ffprobe_duration = `ffprobe -v error -show_entries format=duration -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 ${your_webm_file}`;

exec(cmd_ffprobe_duration, (error, duration, stderr) => {
  if (error || stderr)
    return console.error('Can\'t determine webm file duration');
  console.log(duration);  // 30.543000
});
```

And for those like me that doesn't know what is [ll](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/137705).

Comment: thanks, but in this case output of `ffprobe -v error -show_entries format=duration -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 audiofiles/audiofile.webm` is `N/A`

Comment: Sorry, no luck this time... Maybe you'll have to set the metadata duration when you generate it. Don't know much about MediaRecorder API.

Answer (score 0):

Here a solution, starting from Tgrif proposal.
The bash script below convert the input webm file to a intermediate/temporary wav file.

```
$ cat com/duration
#!/bin/bash

#
# calculate duration in seconds of a webm file
# converting it in a wav temporary file
#
# usage: com/duration audiofiles/audiofile.webm
#

INPUT_FILE=$1
TMP_FILE=$1.wav

ffmpeg -loglevel panic -i $INPUT_FILE -y $TMP_FILE
ffprobe -v error -show_entries format=duration -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 $TMP_FILE
rm $TMP_FILE
```

usage:

```
$ com/duration audiofiles/audiofile.webm 
28.380000


$ time com/duration audiofiles/audiofile.webm 
28.380000

real    0m0.182s
user    0m0.151s
sys 0m0.031s
```

My script appears to me more a workaround and I still ask a better (faster) solution

**UPGRADE**

An alternative solution / workaround I adopted is to just measure on the browser js program the elapsed in msecs with a timer ([Performance.now()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now)) from the `MediaRecorder.start()` to the `MediaRecorder.stop()`